# Need help in simplifying this $y=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{7}i-3}+\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{7}i-3}}{2\sqrt[3]{2^2}}$

Tags: complex-numbers, rational-numbers

Need help in simplifying this:$$y=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{7}i-3}+\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{7}i-3}}{2\sqrt[3]{2^2}}$$
This has real and imaginary parts, at first glance, but after a numerical evaluation in mathematica, $y$ is *effectively* real, as shown by:
$$y=0.692184 + 0. i\Rightarrow y=0.692184 $$
But I have no idea how to simplify this.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @JohnGlenn I got approximately $-0.139+0.242i$ from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(+((sqrt7)i-3)%5E(1%2F3)+-+((sqrt7)i%2B3)%5E(1%2F3)+)+%2F+(2+*+2%5E(2%2F3))). Can you check your evaluation again?

Comment: @TobyMak Apologies, there are some typos

Comment: Sry. Looks like a result from Cardanic formulas.

Comment: @Nebr Yes, it is a solution to a cubic polynomial. I wonder if it can be simplified by hand

Comment: MMA code,Try: `((Sqrt[7]*I - 3)^(1/3) + (-Sqrt[7]*I - 3)^(1/3))/(2*2^(2/3)) // Re // 
  ComplexExpand // TrigFactor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that every complex number $z=x+iy$ can be written as $z=re^{i\varphi}$. Also, $e^{i\varphi}=\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi$.

Thus, with $z=-3+i\sqrt{7}$ we can write:

$$y=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{7}i-3}+\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{7}i-3}}{2\sqrt[3]{2^2}}\\
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{2^2}}\left(z^{\frac{1}{3}}+\left(z^*\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\\
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{2^2}}\left(r^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{i\frac{\varphi}{3}}+r^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{-i\frac{\varphi}{3}}\right)\\
=\frac{r^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2\sqrt[3]{2^2}}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\varphi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\varphi}{3}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\varphi}{3}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{\varphi}{3}\right)\right)\\
=\frac{r^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{2^2}}\cos\left(\frac{\varphi}{3}\right)\in\mathbb{R}$$